# Electrons scattering vs. electrons scattering + photon

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, scattering, scattering-cross-section

I looking for ratio of probabilities of 2 processes:

$$
e^+ +  e^- \to e^+ +  e^-
$$

$$
e^+ +  e^- \to e^+ +  e^- + \gamma
$$

as function of photon energy and momentum.

I think it is well-known result, but I can't find answer.

Comment: Have you heard of "radiative corrections"?...the experimental ones, not RGE stuff. (e.g. https://inspirehep.net/literature/248678)

Comment: @JEB, no, but I am interested in theoretical ones, could you give references to result of such calculation?

Comment: Mo and Tsai: https://www2.cose.isu.edu/~tforest/Classes/NucSim/MoandTsi_RadCorections_Rev.Mod.Phys._vol41_pg205_1969.pdf